# EF4 Code First: how to add a relationship without adding a navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, code-first, ef-code-first

How should I define relationships using Code First but without using any navigation properties?

Previously I have defined One-Many and Many-Many by using navigation properties in both ends of the relationship. And the appropriate relationships are created in the database. here's a stripped down version of how the classes look like (I've converted the Many-Many relationships to one-many for simplicity).

```
public class User 
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public bool IsDisabled { get; set; }
    public DateTime AccessExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public bool MustChangePassword { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Right> Rights { get; set; }
}

public class Right
{
    public Guid RightId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

However, if I remove the navigation properties, no relationships are being created. Here's how the classes would look like.

```
public class User 
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public bool IsDisabled { get; set; }
    public DateTime AccessExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public bool MustChangePassword { get; set; }

    public int Role RoleId { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Right
{
    public Guid RightId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

notice that instead of a navigation property, I have the primary key of the related table. Everything gets created on the table - except the relationship. So how do I get about doing this?

BTW, I've tried various combinations in the OnModelCreating method of the dbcontext but to no avail. Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks,
Mel

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe you always need navigation property on at least one side when using code-first. Then you will be able to map it:

```
public class User  
{     
    public string UserId { get; set; }     
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }     
    public bool IsDisabled { get; set; }     
    public DateTime AccessExpiryDate { get; set; }     
    public bool MustChangePassword { get; set; }      
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}  

public class Role 
{     
    public int RoleId { get; set; }     
    public string Name { get; set; }     
    public string Description { get; set; } 
}  

public class Right 
{     
    public Guid RightId { get; set; }     
    public string Name { get; set; }     
    public string Description { get; set; }      
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
} 

public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext() : base("Entities")
    {}

    protected override void  OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasRequired(r => r.Role)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.RoleId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Right>()
            .HasRequired(r => r.Role)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.RoleId);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have suspected as much. Thanks for the example. I have tried using navigation properties along with the foreign key but the foreign key is not populated, but it looks like the answer is in your example. Thanks!

Comment: Would you need to define the ID properties if a property exists for the actual object? So in the User object would you need to define the RoleId or is that just for convenience?

Comment: @DDiVita: It is a big difference if you define `RoleId` in `User` or not. I recommend this answer to see a difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations/5282275#5282275

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [fluent api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#1.8) to add the relationship, though the "configuration" code is separate from the entity code making it less discoverable.

Answer (score -1):

In EF 4.3, you can add a Migration that adds the relationship.

Comment: This answer would benefit from an example of how to use that feature.