# How to get parent entity key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use EntityFramework and in my edmx file I have two tables mapped:

Customers 
column: 
Id PK

and Orders 
columns:
Id PK
CustomerId FK

which are associated.

When I take Order object there IS Customer property but I can't see CustomerId property.
I used to work with L2SQL and I expected to see CustomerId but EF somehow hides it.

Comment: Be aware that relations with and without a foreign key property are handled differently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations/5282275#5282275

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Add Association dialog in the EF edmx designer allows you to specify (via a checkbox) whether or not you want to have a "Foreign Key" (and/or a Navigation Property) created for the association. did you make sure it's checked?

Comment: I was just going to write that too ;) Now I only paste the link I still have in my clipboard in the comment here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnforum/archive/2010/05/07/foreign-key-association-in-entity-framework-4.aspx There is a screenshot of the wizard in VS2010. It's worth to be noted that this is an EF 4 option which isn't available EF 1 (.NET 3.5SP1).

Comment: I can't check it: This functionality is not available in the target framework ... (3.5)

Comment: @jpl: Indeed, it doesn't exist in EF 1 (.NET 3.5). You have to load the customer then to get the foreign key. Or upgrade to .NET 4 if you can.

Comment: yeah, that was added in EF 4 (check @Slauma's link)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Customer property, there should be a CustomerId property.

So try..

```
myOrderObject.Customer.CustomerId
```

Comment: This might force EF to load the customer object (if you have enabled lazy loading). If you want only the ID, this could be a bad idea ...

Comment: I can't use myOrderObject.Customer.CustomerId because myOrderObject.Customer can be null (yes!)

Comment: Then add a null check. If it isn't null, use the object.

Comment: I wrote '2 tables' for simplicity, actually it's more complicated and I apparently must use couple 'Include' in query. I think I stay with L2SQL then

Answer (score 0):

How exactly is the id column in the order table named? Usually the EF-Designer should create a property for each column in the database table. Have a look at the "Mapping details" page (which you can open in the context menu of the EF designer) to see if (and to which property) the column is mapped.