# creating foreign key in ef 3.5 vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, .net-3.5

Does anyone know of a work around to create foreign keys in the VS2010 Entity Framework designer for .Net 3.5?

Ik can make the assocation but not select the foreign key, can it be done from code?

Thanks.

Comment: Just placing this to keep context of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735725/foreign-key-values-without-navigation-properties

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Exposing foreign keys in your model is a feature which [has been added in .NET 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2010/01/11/entity-framework-in-net-4.aspx). It's not available in .NET 3.5 SP1 (or earlier). That's the reason why this option is disabled in the designer when you target .NET 3.5.