# remove foreign key property cause an exception

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, mapping, entity-relationship

I don't want to use foreign key association to CompanyType (member that will hold the foreign key id) but prefer to use navigation property. So I removed the CompanyTypeId.

I get this exception that relates the relationship between entity Company and CompanyType:

> Error 5: The element 'Principal' in
>   namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm'
>   has incomplete content. List of
>   possible elements expected:
>   'PropertyRef' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm'.

[image]

How can I remove those id's from the POCOs without getting the exception?

Comment: What order did you try to remove them in?

Comment: @Tyler Ferraro: What do you meen?

Comment: well typically you can't remove CompanyTypeId until you remove the constraint making it a foreign key to ID.  Once that constraint is removed, then you can remove the CompanyTypeId from Company.

Comment: @Tyler Ferraro: But if I'll remove the FK constraint - does it know how to load the navigation properties?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the difference between [Foreign key association and Independent association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations/5282275#5282275). Both associations use navigation properties but only Foreign key association uses FK property as well. You can either remove them globally as @Robbie mentioned or you can change the type manually for selected relation.

- Select the relation in entity framework designer
- In properties remove Referential constraints
- Go to Mapping window and map the relation

Here is the screen shot from one of my testing application with one-to-many relation between `Order` and `OrderLine` entities:

[image]

As you can see there is no `OrderId` in the `OrderLine` entity and referential constraints of the relation are empty. Also mapping of the relation is specified.

**BUT** you can't never remove `Id` from `CompanyType`. Ids (PKs) are mandatory. You can only change its accessibility in its properties.

Comment: How can I do Insert (determine the CompanyTypeId) if I remove the CompanyTypeId from Company entity?

Comment: @Noar: You must assign the navigation property `company.CompanyType = ...;`

Answer (score 4):

When you imported in your Model from your DB you are asked if you want to:

"Include Foreign key columns in the model"
you need to switch this off.

[image]

Comment: If I'll remove the foreign key constraint from the entity data model - doed the ef will know to load the navigation properties??

Comment: The Entity Propertys will still be created, it  is on the FK columns that wont be :)

Comment: Rescued from EF inheritance based errors bafflement. Thank you.