# DbContext's ChangeTracker problem

Tags: code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I have a codefirst EF-4.1 based program. The user gets a context and can modify some properties. When the user is done, I do a quick

```
ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(e => e.State != EntityState.Unchanged);
```

to determine if a `SaveChanges()` is required or not. If I do a 'SaveChanges()' call, the changes that have made are persisted to the database.

This works for some properties, and doesn't work for others. Specifically it seems to work with simple types (`float`s), and with collection hierarchies(`ObservableCollection`s).

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this is a problem. Some relations are not tracked by `DbChangeTracker`. There is difference between [Independent association and Foreign key association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations/5282275#5282275). Changes to relation are tracked in case of:

- One-to-one relation which is always Foreign key association in EFv4+
- One-to-many relation with Foreign key association - you should set up foreign key property

Changes to relation are not tracked in case of:

- One-to-many relation with Independent association
- Many-to-many relation which is always Independent association

Not tracked for Independent association is not correct naming. These changes are tracked but `DbChangeTracker` [does not expose access to these changes](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/192f6f64-df77-4902-901b-c36e2b157ab6)! You must convert `DbContext` to `ObjectContext` and use `ObjectStateManager` to get access to `ObjectStateEntries` representing independent associations.

In this case the easiest thing is simply call `SaveChanges` always. It will not execute any DB commands if no data need to be saved.

Comment: After some testing, I've opted in for always SaveChanges(). As you mention, this call is cheap if there are no changes to persist.