# Entity Framework Code First and relations

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a Post class for a website representing posts made on the website.
Each post is part of a category, and I have a corresponding Category class.
How would I relate posts to categories? By letting the post have an `int CategoryId` or a `Category Category`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code First: Independent associations vs. Foreign key associations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do both. This allows full navigation of the caterogy from post, but also gives you the foreign key if that is all you need.

```
public int CategoryID { get; set; }

public virtual Catergory Category { get; set; }
```

Comment: Does `Category Category` just map to a foreign key? I.e. without the `Category Category`, there will be no foreign key relation between Category and Post?

Comment: Yeah, the crucial bit that forms the actual relationship is the Category Category.