# Foreign Keys in Entity Framework - Cycles or multiple cascade paths error

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, ef-code-first

Using EF Code First i have the following, for example:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogID { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BlogMeta> BlogMeta { get; set; }
}

public class BlogMeta
{
    public int BlogMetaID { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

This successfully generates the tables Blog and BlogMeta and creates the foreign key relationship with the User table. After reading [this](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) i changed this to the following:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogID { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BlogMeta> BlogMeta { get; set; }
}

public class BlogMeta
{
    public int BlogMetaID { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public int BlogID { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

and now it doesn't work. It generates the tables and then throws the following error when trying to create the relationships:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'BlogMeta_User' on table 'BlogMeta' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.

So what is the advantage of introducing the `public int UserID` and why does it fail when doing so?

**EDIT:**
Ok, so i've come across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations) which outlines the difference between Independent Associations and Foreign Key Associations... which it turns out is what i was talking about. So this leaves the question, why does it throw the above error when using foreign key associations?

Comment: What is relation between `Blog` and `BlogMeta`? The error you see means that more than one cascade path exists to BlogMeta entity which is not supported in SQL server.

Comment: I've updated the question, there is a one-to-many relation between the two. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

As Ladislav mentioned, you are defining multiple cascade paths for `BlogMeta` entity. You'd have to disable cascade for one of your relationships.

You can add the following method to your context class, to diable cascade for your User-BlogMeta relationship:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<BlogMeta>().HasRequired(bm => bm.User).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

You can indicate the other end of relationship (`WithMany(u => u.BlogMetas)`) if you have defined a colletion of `BlogMeta` in your `User` class.