# Entity framework 5 Self Reference Probloem "cycles or multiple cascade paths "

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

hi every one i have a problem with EF5.
i have a Comment class with has an ICollection witch are its replies but when i try to update database there is this error:

Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Comment_dbo.Comment_ParentComment_Id' on table 'Comment' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

i tried other solutions on stackoverflow but none worked.
here is my Comment class:

```
public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SenderName { get; set; }
    public string SenderEmail { get; set; }
    public string SenderWebSite { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Positives { get; set; }
    public int Minuses { get; set; }
    public bool Confirmed { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Comment> Replies { get; set; }
    public Comment ParentComment { get; set; }
    public int? ParentCommentId { get; set; }

    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public Article Article { get; set; }
}
```

and my fluent api:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Replies)

            .WithRequired(c => c.ParentComment)

            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentCommentId)

            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Thanks any for reading or answering.

Comment: It's a limitation of SQL Server not EF. If you want the referential integrity, don't have cascaded deletes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foreign Keys in Entity Framework - Cycles or multiple cascade paths error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946793/foreign-keys-in-entity-framework-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths-error)