# Adding detached entities to a 1-many relationship in EF 4.1 Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I am attempting to use EF 4.1 Code First to model a simple relationship of a User having a single Role.  When I attempt to save an existing User with a **new** Role to a different context (using a different context to simulate a client-server round-trip), I get the following exception:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details. ---> **System.Data.UpdateException: A relationship from the 'User_CurrentRole' AssociationSet is in the 'Added' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'User_CurrentRole_Source' must also in the 'Added' state.**

What I expect is that a new Role is created and associated with the exising User.
What am I doing wrong, is this possible to achieve in EF 4.1 code first?  The error message seems to suggest that it needs both the User and the Role to be in the added state, but I'm modifying an exising User, so how can that be?

Things to note: I'd like to avoid modifying the structure of the entities (eg by introducing foreign key properties visible on the entities), and in the database I'd like the User to have a foreign key pointing to Role (not the other way around).  I'm also not prepared to move to Self Tracking Entities (unless there's no other way).

Here are the entities:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Role CurrentRole { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the mapping I'm using:

```
public class UserRolesContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(u => u.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasKey(r => r.RoleId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasRequired(u => u.CurrentRole);
    }
}
```

I pre-populate the database with this:

```
public class UserInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<UserRolesContext>
{
        protected override void Seed(UserRolesContext context)
        {
            context.Users.Add(new User() {Name = "Bob", 
                                          CurrentRole = new Role() {Description = "Builder"}});
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

And finally, here's the failing test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CanModifyDetachedUserWithRoleAndReattach()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<UserRolesContext>(new UserInitializer());
        var context = new UserRolesContext();

        // get the existing user
        var user = context.Users.AsNoTracking().Include(c => c.CurrentRole).First(u => u.UserId == 1);

        //modify user, and attach to a new role
        user.Name = "MODIFIED_USERNAME";
        user.CurrentRole = new Role() {Description = "NEW_ROLE"};

        var newContext = new UserRolesContext();
        newContext.Users.Attach(user);
        // attachment doesn't mark it as modified, so mark it as modified manually
        newContext.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
        newContext.Entry(user.CurrentRole).State = EntityState.Added;

        newContext.SaveChanges();

        var verificationContext = new UserRolesContext();
        var afterSaveUser = verificationContext.Users.Include(c => c.CurrentRole).First(u => u.UserId == 1);
        Assert.AreEqual("MODIFIED_USERNAME", afterSaveUser.Name, "User should have been modified");
        Assert.IsTrue(afterSaveUser.CurrentRole != null, "User used to have a role, and should have retained it");
        Assert.AreEqual("NEW_ROLE", afterSaveUser.CurrentRole.Description, "User's role's description should  have changed.");
    }
}
}
```

Surely this is a scenario that's covered, I would guess it's something I'm missing in the way I've defined the model mapping?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have broken EF state model. You mapped your entity with mandatory `CurrentRole` so EF knows that you cannot have existing `User` without the `Role`. You have also used [independent associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations/5282275#5282275) (no FK property exposed on your entity). It means that relation between role and user is another tracked entry which has its state. When you assign the role to existing user the relation entry has state set to `Added` but it is not possible for existing `User` (because it must have already role assigned) unless you mark the old relation as `Deleted` (or unless you are working with a new user). Solving this in detached scenario is [very hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635071/update-relationships-when-saving-changes-of-ef4-poco-objects/3635326#3635326) and it leads to the code where you must pass information about old role during the roundtrip and manually play with state manager or with entity graph itself. Something like:

```
Role newRole = user.CurrentRole; // Store the new role to temp variable
user.CurrentRole = new Role { Id = oldRoleId }; // Simulate old role from passed Id

newContext.Users.Attach(user);
newCotnext.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
newContext.Roles.Add(newRole);

user.CurrentRole = newRole; // Reestablish the role so that context correctly set the state of the relation with the old role

newContext.SaveChanges();
```

The simplest solution is load the old state from the database and merge changes from the new state to the loaded (attached) one. This can be also avoided by exposing FK properties.

Btw. your model is not one to one but one to many where the role can be assigned to multiple users - in case of one-to-one it would be even more complicated because you will have to delete the old role prior to creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav, it's very dissapointing to hear that EF code-first doesn't support this scenario easily with the object model I described (i.e. without STEs and without FK properties).  Introducing the FK as a property seems like a dirty work-around, as does keeping track of the changes and manually merging them.  Fortunately this is very early on in the project, so we might evaluate NHibernate to see if it better suits us.