# Do I need to use a property ClassId to represent a relationship in the Code First (Entity Framework)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, entity-relationship

I am using the entity framework (code first).

I would like to know if I really need to use a property with Id for relationship with another entity as in the code below.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    public Profile Profile{ get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }
}
```

For this way when I insert a user by setting the profileid property performs perfectly.

But when I don't use the profileid property in the Profile class,

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Profile Profile{ get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }
}
```

the execution the insert method adds another profile record. Why?

My mapping:

```
public class EntityMapping<Entity> : EntityTypeConfiguration<Entity> where Entity : EntityBase
{
    public EntityMapping()
    {
        HasKey(e => e.Id);
        Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}

public class UserMapping : EntityMapping<User>
{
    public UserMapping() : base()
    {
         ToTable("USER");
         Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("USER_CD_USER");
         Property(p => p.Login).HasColumnName("USER_TX_LOGIN").HasMaxLength(10).IsRequired();
         Property(p => p.Password).HasColumnName("USUA_TX_PASSWORD").HasMaxLength(8).IsRequired();
         HasRequired(e => e.Profile).WithMany(p => p.Users).Map(p => p.MapKey("PROF_CD_PROFILE"));
     }
}

public class ProfilelMapping : EntityMapping<Profile>
{
    public ProfileMapping()
        : base()
    {
        ToTable("PROFILE");
        Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("PROF_CD_PROFILE");
        Property(p => p.Description).HasColumnName("PROFILE_DS_PROFILE").HasMaxLength(20).IsRequired();
        HasMany(e => e.Users).WithRequired(p => p.Profile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking two questions.

> Do I need to use FK property?

No you don't but EF behavior changes if you use it or not. More about it is in [separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations/5282275#5282275) and linked blog article.

> Why EF inserts Profile again?

Creating relations with existing entities requires special care. EF doesn't check if your entity exists in the database - you must tell it to EF. Here is one of many ways how to achieve that (without loading profile from the database):

```
var user = GetNewUserSomewhere();
context.Users.Add(user);

// Dummy profile representing existing one.
var profile = new Profile() { Id = 1 };
// Informing context about existing profile.
context.Profiles.Attach(profile);

// Creating relation between new user and existing profile
user.Profile = profile;

context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: Yes. It's the way EF work. It needs to store the foreign key in a dedicated property. Have you ever generated the class structure from a database? It always adds that key property. There are cases you don't need the `Profile` property loaded, but later you might want to retrieve it. That's what the dedicated `ProfileId` property is used, it will read the key value from there and load the object.

Comment: [EF doesn't need](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations/5282275#5282275) to store FK in dedicated property.