# MapKey vs HasForeignKey Difference - Fluent Api

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-relationship

What is actually the difference between:

```
this.HasRequired(a => a.Something)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(a => a.MapKey("SomethingId"));
```

and

```
this.HasRequired(a => a.Something)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(a => a.SomethingId);
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Both mappings will create exactly the same database schema with a non-nullable foreign key `SomethingId` and a referential constraint between the two related tables.

The first mapping with `MapKey` is used when you don't want to have the foreign key as a property in your model class. The type of association in this case is called *Independent Association*. You would apply the second mapping with `HasForeignKey` when the foreign key is a property in the model. This type is called *Foreign Key Association*.

In many scenarios it is easier to work with Foreign Key Associations, but many people consider it as less clean to have a relational artifact (a foreign key) in the object world and prefer Independent Associations therefore.

Here are some references about the two types of associations and their Pros and Cons:

- http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/05/foreign-key-vs-independent-associations-in-ef-4/
- [What are Independent Associations and Foreign Key Associations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606948/what-are-independent-associations-and-foreign-key-associations)
- [Code First: Independent associations vs. Foreign key associations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations)

Comment: "Many people think that an object-relational mapping tool is suppose to solve the object-relational impedance mismatch rather than forcing or even encouraging you to make your object model look like it was designed specifically around how the data is persisted".  There, I fixed it for you.

Comment: My thoughts exactly! If there's a foreign key in the database then either the distinction between MapKey and HasForeignKey is practically meaningless, or you've made a poor design decision. IMNSHO.