# Unable to resolve service for type

Tags: c#

I have an interface to a send mail async function which I am using for my email functions in my controller class.

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
                         SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
                         IEmailSender emailSender)
{
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
}
```

As you see I am using the `IEmailSender emailSender` to create the object and setting it to its instance in the routine `AccountController`.

The interface is simply made up of one constructor

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace solitude.admin.core.Interfaces
{
    public interface IEmailSender
    {
        Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message);
    }
}
```

But the problem is when I come to view my view I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'solitude.admin.core.Interfaces.IEmailSender' while attempting to activate 'solitude.admin.core.Controllers.AccountController'.
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)

Comment: did you register it in your IoC?

Comment: @KhanhTO Ioc ? sorry dont understand what you mean can you please demonstrate in an answer. Its only one class there is not another class with this name.

Comment: It seems you're using dependency injection, the exception occurring is likely the cause of missing registration

Comment: And how does one solve this

Comment: Once you register a type that implement IEmailSender it can be resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register how the DI engine will provide an `IEmailSender`.  Assuming you are using asp.net core, you do this is in your `Startup.cs` in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
   ...
   services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSenderImplementation>();
   ...
}
```

This is where `EmailSenderImplementation` is a class that implements the `IEmailSender` interface.

This registration tells the DI framework how to get an implementation of `IEmailSender`.  In my example I am telling it to instantiate a single instance of `EmailSenderImplementation` and reuse that instance over the lifetime of the application.  You might need to use `AddTransient` (if you want a new one every time you ask for one) or `AddScoped` (if you want a new one for each http request) instead of `AddSingleton` depending on how your implementation of `IEmailSender` works.

Comment: I noticed you have another type here EmailSenderImplementation what is it and how should it be created

Comment: `EmailSenderImplementation` was the dummy name I made up for whatever class you need to write that implements IEmailSender.  Your answer below with `AuthMessageSender` is exactly such an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Tim was indeed correct what I had to do was add this following code to my configure startup.cs

```
services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
```

The class AuthMessageSender is made up of as follows.

```
// This class is used by the application to send Email and SMS
// when you turn on two-factor authentication in ASP.NET Identity.
// For more details see this link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532713
public class AuthMessageSender : IEmailSender 
{
   public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
   {
            // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
            return Task.FromResult(0);
    }         
}
```

This allowed me to call the function from the class as normal I guess old .net new how to handle this can someone explain to me why this has changed in core why do we have to hard wire like this.