# To edit a many to many relationship in Entity Framework, why must I clear the collection first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following code for editing the departments a user is in. For some reason, `method1` causes EF to try and insert the relationship again (and causing a primary key error), where `method2` succeeds.

Why does the code of `method1` not know that by reassigning the value, I only want the new collection of departments? Is `method2` the preferred method to update values? I haven't had to do it this way with one to many relationships.

```
public class User
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public void Method1(list<Department> departments, string userId)
{
    var user = DbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u=> u.Id == userId);
    user.departments = departments;
    db.SaveChanges()
}

public void Method2(list<Department> departments, string userId) 
{
    var user = DbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u=> u.Id == userId);
    user.departments.clear();
    user.departments = departments;
    db.SaveChanges()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below on *departments*, I will mean `Users2Departments` table.

Probably, it happened because, when you wrote `user.departments.clear();` you loaded all related *departments*(via `LazyLoading`), so they become trackable by `EF` and were successfully marked as `Deleted`(after `clear()` call). And then new *departments* were assigned to `user`, i.e. marked as `Added`. All is correct.

But, if you just perform only assigning: `user.departments = departments`, `EF` will not know or not care, that there are existed *departments* and it should delete them, because, at least, they are not tracked, because they not loaded, since `user.departments` literal is located at **Left**HandSide(`user.departments.clear()` is **Right**HandSide). Moreover `Users2Departments` table is implicit table. So `EF` only inserts new *departments* without deletion of previous ones, so exception will may occur.

Comment: Correct. Many-to-many associations can only be manipulated as [*independent associations*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12606948/861716).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So what is the correct way to update independent associations?

Comment: @ChrisChevalier, at first, load departments: `var dep = user.departments;`, then you can remove some of them: `user.departments.Remove(dep[0]);` or add new one: `user.departments.Add(newDep)`, but at last case `newDep` should not initially exists at `user.departments`, to avoid `PK` exception.