# Update linked table with property ids on updating an object in the db

Tags: entity-framework

I have an object `MyProduct` which has a property - a `List` of type `List<Category>`.

When I insert `MyProduct` with `dbContext.SaveChanges()` to the db the product gets inserted into the relevant table in the db and the list of properties get inserted into a linked table in the database which has double primary key eg. `ProductId` and `CategoryId` - for each category in the `List<Category>`.

When I'm trying to update the product and assign the same categories to `MyProduct` then product gets updated but the context is trying to insert again same category ids values into the linked table.

```
MyProduct product = _repo.GetProduct(productDto.ProductId);
product.Categories = categories;
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

What I need it to do is rather delete existing pairs `ProductId` + `CategoryId` and insert them again according to the values provided in `List<Category>` in `MyProduct`
or similar, but don't want it to attempt to insert same values again.

How to achieve it?

Comment: Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47043697/to-edit-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-entity-framework-why-must-i-clear-the-co/47070617#47070617). Spoiler: call `product.Categories.Clear();` before assigning.

Comment: This will only clear the property `List` not the database entries

Comment: Did you tried it?

Comment: Yes, and I'm still getting the same: `SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.CategoryProducts'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.CategoryProducts'. The duplicate key value is (9, 125).` Strange thing is that first run debugging it didn't hit the error, second and next time debugging it did.

Comment: And if I try to insert another category it does insert new record in `CategoryProducts` table without deleting the old one.