# Entity Framework Relationships between two poco objects

Tags: entity-framework

I am very new to the Entity Framework, having decided that once and for all I am going to do a project using it and get some practice. I have a question regarding POCO object relationships for CodeFirst development.

The examples I have seen would layout an object like this:

```
public class Fruit {
     public int FruitId { get; set; }
     public string FruitName { get; set; }
}

public class Basket {
     public int BasketId { get; set; }
     public int FruitId { get; set; }
     public Fruit Contents { get; set; }
}
```

My question is, in the basket class, why define a FruitId and a Fruit Object? Wouldn't the existence of the Fruit Object imply the Id value?

Comment: `FruitId` is the FK in the database schema and `Fruit` is the [navigation property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) to the related object but doesn't show up on the DB.

Comment: There's a bunch of information out there about why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915938/in-what-scenarios-do-i-need-foreign-keys-and-navigation-properties-in-entity-fra

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253234/what-is-the-point-of-creating-foreign-key-properties-when-using-entity-framework

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations

Comment: Also your Contents suggest plural Fruits, but you only have a singel entity. A basket should contain more than one fruit I guess, so it should have been List<Fruit> Contents?? That requires different mapping schemes.