# Saving single objects with Entity Framework code first

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-4.3

I am using Entity Framework 4.3.1 in a project, using code first and the DbContext API.  My app is an n-tier app where disconnected objects may come in from a client.  I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 but will be moving to SQL Azure soon.  I am running into an issue I just can't seem to solve.

Imagine I have a few classes:

```
class A {
    // Random stuff here
}
class B {
    // Random stuff here
    public A MyA { get; set; }
}
class C {
    // Random stuff here
    public A MyA { get; set; }
}
```

By default, EF operates on object graphs.  For instance, if I have an instance of B that encapsulates an instance of A and I call `myDbSet.Add(myB);`, it will also mark the instance of A as being added (assuming it is not yet being tracked).

I have a scenario in my app where I need to be explicit about which objects get persisted to the database, rather than have it track entire object graphs.  The order of operations is as follows:

```
A myA = new A(); // Represents something already in DB that doesn't need to be udpated.
C myC = new C() { // Represents something already in DB that DOES need to be updated.
    A = myA;
}
B myB0 = new B() { // Not yet in DB.
    A = myA;
}
B myB1 = new B() { // Not yet in DB.
    A = myA;
}

myDbSetC.Attach(myC);
context.Entry(myC).State = Modified;

myDbSetB.Add(myB0); // Tries to track myA with a state of Added
myDbSetB.Add(myB1);

context.SaveChanges();
```

At this point I get an error saying `AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.`  I believe this happens because calling add on myB0 marks the instance of A as being Added, which conflicts with the instance of A already being tracked.

Ideally I could do something like call `myDbSet.AddOnly(myB)`, but obviously we don't have that option.

I have tried several workarounds:

**Attempt #1:**
First, I tried creating a helper method to prevent myA from being added a second time.

```
private void MarkGraphAsUnchanged<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class {
        DbEntityEntry entryForThis = this.context.Entry<TEntity>(entity);
        IEnumerable<DbEntityEntry> entriesItWantsToChange = this.context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Distinct();

        foreach (DbEntityEntry entry in entriesItWantsToChange) {
            if (!entryForThis.Equals(entry)) {
                entry.State = System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged;
            }
        }
    }

...

myDbSetB.Add(myB0);
MarkGraphAsUnchanged(myB0);
```

While this solves the problem of it trying to add myA, it still causes key violations within the ObjectStateManager.

**Attempt #2:**
I tried doing the same as above, but setting the state to Detached instead of Unchanged.  This works for saving, but it insists on setting `myB0.A = null`, which has other adverse effects in my code.

**Attempt #3:**
I used a TransactionScope around my the entire DbContext.  However, even when calling `SaveChanges()` between each `Attach()` and `Add()`, the change tracker does not flush its tracked entries so I have the same problem as in attempt #1.

**Attempt #4:**
I continued with the TransactionScope, except I used a repository/DAO pattern and internally create a new DbContext and call `SaveChanges()` for each distinct operation I do.  In this case, I got an error 'Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows.'  When using the SQL Profiler, I find that when calling `SaveChanges()` on the *second* operation I did (the first `Add()`), it actually sends the `UPDATE` SQL to the database from the *first* operation a second time -- but doesn't change any rows.  This feels like a bug in Entity Framework to me.

**Attempt #5:**
Instead of using the TransactionScope, I decided to use use a DbTransaction only.  I still create multiple contexts but pass a pre-built EntityConnection to each new context as it's created (by caching and manually opening the EntityConnection built by the first context).  However, when I do this, the second context runs an initializer I have defined, even though it would have already run when the app first started up.  In a dev environment I have this seeding some test data, and it actually times out wating for a database lock on a table my first `Attach()` modified (but is still locked due to the transaction still being open).

Help!!  I've tried about everything I can think of, and short of completely refactoring my app to not use navigation properties or using manually constructed DAOs to do INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements, I'm at a loss.  It seems there must be a way to get the benefits of Entity Framework for O/R mapping but still manually controlling operations within a transaction!

Comment: Have you tried just attaching myA?  You will need to do this before attaching anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be something else you are not showing because there is no problem with the way how you attach and add entities. The following code will attach `myA`, `myC`, `myB0` and `myB1` to context as unchanged and set state of `myC` to modified.

```
myDbSetC.Attach(myC);
context.Entry(myC).State = Modified;
```

the following code will correctly detect that all entities are already attached and instead of throwing exception (as it would do in ObjectContext API) or inserting all entities again (as you expect) it would just change `myB0` and `myB1` to added state:

```
myDbSetB.Add(myB0);
myDbSetB.Add(myB1);
```

If your `myA` and `myC` are correctly initialized with keys of existing entities whole code will correctly execute and save except the single problem:

```
C myC = new C() { 
    A = myA;
}
```

This looks like [independent association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations/5282275#5282275) and independent association has its own state but API to set its state is [not available in DbContext API](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/192f6f64-df77-4902-901b-c36e2b157ab6). If this is a new relation you want to save it will not be saved because it is still tracked as unchanged. You must either use foreign key association or you must convert your context to `ObjectContext`:

```
ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
```

and use `ObjectStateManager` to [change state of the relation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487276.aspx).

Comment: You are correct, these are independent associations. You said "If your myA and myC are correctly initialized with keys of existing entities". My assumption is that the change tracker/state manager is using those keys to identify the various entries. After more analysis (my actual object graph is much more complex), there is one case where there are two objects, let's call them As. They have the same keys and contents but are different instances in memory.  That causes problems: the duplicate A gets added along with the B despite an A already being tracked with the same keys.

Comment: You must not have two instances for the same entity. It will always result in problems or exception.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I'll go through and ensure object instances are the same and see if I'm still having problems.  It's unfortunate this restriction applies, and that there is not a way to bypass change tracking and do each operation manually.  I also still think there are some issues related to the multiple contexts within the same transaction...although those are likely different from this multiple instances issue.  Regardless, if ensuring the instances are the same solves the problem I'll accept the answer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As Ladislav suggested, I got the object instances consistent, which solved the problem of it trying to add redundant As.

As it turns out, both B0 and B1 actually encapsulate other objects (D0 and D1, respectively) which in turn encapsulate A.  Both D0 and D1 were already in the database but not being tracked by Entity.

Adding B0/B1 caused D0/D1 to also be inserted, erroneously. I ended up using the object context API Ladislav suggested to both mark the ObjectStateEntry for D0/D1 to Unchanged, and the relationships between D0/D1 and A as Unchanged.  This seems to do what I need: update C and insert B0/B1 only.

Below is my code to do this, which I call right before SaveChanges.  Note that I'm sure there are still some edge cases that are not handled, and this is not throughly tested -- but it should give a *rough* idea what needs to be done.

```
// Entries are put in here when they are explicitly added, modified, or deleted.
private ISet<DbEntityEntry> trackedEntries = new HashSet<DbEntityEntry>();
private void MarkGraphAsUnchanged()
{
    IEnumerable<DbEntityEntry> entriesItWantsToChange = this.context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Distinct();
    foreach (DbEntityEntry entry in entriesItWantsToChange)
    {
        if (!this.trackedEntries.Contains(entry))
        {
            entry.State = System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged;
        }
    }

    IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> allEntries =
            this.context.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)
            .Union(this.context.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Deleted))
            .Union(this.context.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified));

        foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in allEntries)
        {
            if (entry.IsRelationship)
            {
                /* We can't mark relationships are being unchanged if we are truly adding or deleting the entity.
                 * To determine this, we need to first lookup the entity keys, then state entries themselves.
                 */
                EntityKey key1 = null;
                EntityKey key2 = null;
                if (entry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
                {
                    key1 = (EntityKey)entry.OriginalValues[0];
                    key2 = (EntityKey)entry.OriginalValues[1];
                }
                else if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    key1 = (EntityKey)entry.CurrentValues[0];
                    key2 = (EntityKey)entry.CurrentValues[1];
                }

                ObjectStateEntry entry1 = this.context.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(key1);
                ObjectStateEntry entry2 = this.context.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(key2);

                if ((entry1.State != EntityState.Added) && (entry1.State != EntityState.Deleted) && (entry2.State != EntityState.Added) && (entry2.State != EntityState.Deleted))
                {
                    entry.ChangeState(EntityState.Unchanged);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Whew!!! The basic pattern is:

1. Explicitly track changes as they are made.
2. Go back and clean up all the things Entity thinks it needs to do, but doesn't really.
3. Actually save the changes out to the DB.

This having to "go back and clean up" method is obviously sub-optimal, but it seems to be the best option for the moment, without having to manually attach peripheral entities (such as D0/D1) before I attempt any save operation.  Having all this logic in a generic repository helps -- the logic only needs to be written once.  I do hope in a future release, Entity can add this capability directly (and remove the restriction about having multiple instances of an object on the heap but with the same key).