# Bizarre difficulties when adding + modifying objects in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm having lots of trouble with codefirst Entity Framework.

I have a database with two tables - `Users` and `Countries`. `Users` has a field that has a foreign key of `CountryId`. When a user is first added to the database the FK is updated fine. However, if I try to update the FK on a user that I attach to a new DbContext, no changes happens.

I can update the FK in the context that I originally created the user in. Also, I can update the FK in a context where I retrieve the user from the database. However, in a context where I just `Attach` the user, the FK field does not update, even though normal `nvarchar` or `int` fields do update.

Here is my DbContext:

```
class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my model:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

}

public class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This method demonstrates the problem. I add 3 users to my database, and then try to modify them in 3 different ways - in the original context the user was added in, in a new context with `Attach`, and and in new context where the user is retrieved back from the database to modify:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Country[] countries;

    using (var dc = new DataContext())
    {
        countries = dc.Countries.ToArray();
    }

    var u = new User();

    // FIRST ROW
    using (var dc = new DataContext())
    {
        u.Name = "First";
        u.Country = countries[0];
        dc.Users.Attach(u);
        dc.Entry(u).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
        dc.SaveChanges();

        u.Name = "FirstChanged";
        u.Country = countries[1];
        // defaults to 'added' once u is tracked.
        dc.Entry(countries[1]).State = EntityState.Unchanged; 
        dc.SaveChanges();
    }

    // SECOND ROW
    u = new User();
    using (var dc = new DataContext())
    {
        u.Name = "Second";
        u.Country = countries[0];
        dc.Users.Attach(u);
        dc.Entry(u).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
        dc.SaveChanges();
    }

    using (var dc = new DataContext())
    {
        u.Name = "SecondChanged";
        u.Country = countries[1];
        dc.Users.Attach(u);
        dc.Entry(u).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
        dc.SaveChanges();
    }

    // THIRD ROW
    u = new User();
    using (var dc = new DataContext())
    {
        u.Name = "Third";
        u.Country = countries[0];
        dc.Users.Attach(u);
        dc.Entry(u).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
        dc.SaveChanges();
    }

    using (var dc = new DataContext())
    {
        u = dc.Users.Find(u.UserId);
        u.Name = "ThirdChanged";
        u.Country = countries[1];
        dc.Entry(countries[1]).State = EntityState.Modified;
        dc.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This application produces the following results in the database:

```
UserId  Name    Country_CountryId   
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   FirstChanged    2
2   SecondChanged   1
3   ThirdChanged    2
```

As you can see, In all cases `Name` is successfully updated. In the first case and third case, the `CountryId` is updated. However, in the second case the CountryId is not updated. Unfortunately, this is case is most relevant for me, as I want to be able to persist the Model for editing by a user outside of a DataContext.

I don't understand why this is happening - if the `Name` field did not update I could understand, but as its just `CountryId` I can't work out why. In both cases the `Country` object is tracked and marked as `Unchanged`. I can't understand why only the second case doesn't work.

Please help me work out what is up here. The only solution I can think of is to use the third case when I need to modify, so that when I save I copy across data from my persisted object to a new object retrieved from the database which is saved... but obviously this is a silly solution.

Below, I include a console application that demonstrates this problem. To run it you will need to retrieve EntityFramework using NuGet (or similar) and a connection string like this:

```
<add name="DataContext" connectionString="DataSource=.\DataContext.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Country[] countries;

            using (var dc = new DataContext())
            {
                countries = dc.Countries.ToArray();
            }

            var u = new User();

            // FIRST ROW
            using (var dc = new DataContext())
            {
                u.Name = "First";
                u.Country = countries[0];
                dc.Users.Attach(u);
                dc.Entry(u).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
                dc.SaveChanges();

                u.Name = "FirstChanged";
                u.Country = countries[1];
                // defaults to 'added' once u is tracked.
                dc.Entry(countries[1]).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                dc.SaveChanges();
            }

            // SECOND ROW
            u = new User();
            using (var dc = new DataContext())
            {
                u.Name = "Second";
                u.Country = countries[0];
                dc.Users.Attach(u);
                dc.Entry(u).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
                dc.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (var dc = new DataContext())
            {
                u.Name = "SecondChanged";
                u.Country = countries[1];
                dc.Users.Attach(u);
                dc.Entry(u).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
                dc.SaveChanges();
            }

            // THIRD ROW
            u = new User();
            using (var dc = new DataContext())
            {
                u.Name = "Third";
                u.Country = countries[0];
                dc.Users.Attach(u);
                dc.Entry(u).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
                dc.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (var dc = new DataContext())
            {
                u = dc.Users.Find(u.UserId);
                u.Name = "ThirdChanged";
                u.Country = countries[1];
                dc.Entry(countries[1]).State = EntityState.Modified;
                dc.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }

        public DataContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(new ModelInitializer());
            Database.Initialize(false);
        }
    }

    class ModelInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DataContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(DataContext context)
        {
            var jsds = new List<Country>
                {
                    new Country("United Kingdom"),
                    new Country("United States Of America")
                };

            jsds.ForEach(jsd => context.Countries.Add(jsd));
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

    }

    public class Country
    {
        public int CountryId { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Country() { }

        public Country(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for looking at this question - any help would be appreciated. I'm on the second day of trying to fix it and I am slowly going crazy...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is tricky problem based on the difference between [foreign key association vs independent association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations/5282275#5282275). If you use foreign key association (you will have `CountryId` property in your `User` entity) your second case will work as well but you are using independent association where the association itself has its own state which must be set to `Added` to make it work. `DbContext` [doesn't offer API](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/192f6f64-df77-4902-901b-c36e2b157ab6) to change the state of the association so you must use `ObjectContext`.

```
u = new User();
using (var dc = new DataContext())
{
    u.Name = "Second";
    u.Country = countries[0];
    dc.Users.Attach(u);
    dc.Entry(u).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
    dc.SaveChanges();
}

using (var dc = new DataContext())
{
    u.Name = "SecondChanged";
    u.Country = countries[1];
    dc.Users.Attach(u);
    ObjectContext oc = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dc).ObjectContext;
    oc.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(u, EntityState.Modified);
    oc.ObjectStateManager.ChangeRelationshipState(u, countries[1], x => x.Country, EntityState.Added);
    dc.SaveChanges();
}
```

When you use independent associations you can find [a lot of complications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635071/update-relationships-when-saving-changes-of-ef4-poco-objects/3635326#3635326).

Comment: I just want to say that your answers to many EF-related questions have been invaluable to me.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the code that you posted but had some trouble with it (I got an error saying to refresh the `ObjectStateManager`, but doing so meant that `u.Name` did not update, though the FK did...), so I changed my `Users` class to use foreign key association. I then changed my code to assign countries like this: `u.CountryId = countries[0].CountryId;`. Is this correct? It seems to work, but in certain cases the `Country` property is null rather than reflecting the `CountryId` property of the User.

Comment: Yes it is correct way to use FK associations. The name wasn't updated because the code is missing the line to change state of user to modified. I will update the code.