# Entity Framework Code First Relationship

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to figure out how to make this work in EF. I have two entities `Employee` and `User`. I need to make it so the `User` has an optional mapping to the `Employee`. If there is a mapping, then it would be 1:1.

Basically this system can be accessed by employees and also by outside vendors, but I want one table to manage logons: `Users`.

How do I define this realtionship in EF with fluid configurations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set simple fluent configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional(u => u.Employee)
            .WithRequired(e => e.User);
```

or in reverse order:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.User)
            .WithOptional(u => u.Employee);
```

EF will use Employess's PK as FK to user - that is mandatory requirement for EF to correctly use one-to-one relation. In case of Data annotation it is enough to mark Employee's PK with `ForeignKey` attribute pairing it with `User` navigation property:

```
public class Employee {
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So is the fluent config above the same as the annotations? Also, when configuring a 1 - many relationship do I have to have a foreign key field and a navigation property? So in the case of the employee - user, do I have to have (on the employee) UserID and the nav property User?

Comment: Yes the fluent config is the same as the configuration with annotation. When configuring one to many relation you always have FK in the database but the existence of FK property in your class differs between [two possible types of associations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations/5282275#5282275) used in EF.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class User
{
    ...
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

[This tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) may help.

Comment: so all you have to do is define a nullable type? When defining one to many relationships do you have to define a navigation property and a Fk?

Comment: This even doesn't compile because only value types can be made nullable. Reference types are nullable always and `Employee` is reference type.