# Is unit of work a good pattern for transactions that will auto generate new objects (auto_increment id)?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, transactions, domain-driven-design, unit-of-work

From the unit of work pattern i uderstand a method of doing typic transactions based on some domain repostiries (using a repository per domain object) . Example : after defining some repository objects in the UoW object , commit those repositories based on theyr state .

Also the repositories should not contain any transaction logic .

What happens when an insert() leads to a creation of a new object (auto generated id) that later on is needed by another object in the same transaction ?

Unit of work does not seem to work for this case . There could be even more specific and complex transaction where objects are generated when the UoW commit is ran .

How should the transactions be treated in this case ?

Comment: What about retrieve this id manually before saving? What auto-generation strategy you use?

Comment: I'm talking about the auto increment attribute (the rdbms sequencing) .

Comment: like Oracle sequence?

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931034/ef5-incrementing-unique-id-without-calling-savechanges-until-user-request-to-sav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually ORMs like NHibernate or EntityFramework know how to handle the order of calls to DB. E.g. [NHibernate's inverse](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/04/nhibernates-inverse-what-does-it-really.html) is used in order to specify who is responsible for bidirectional relationship.

If you develop your own DataAccessLayer/ORM it is your responsibility to specify the invocation order. **The simplest solution is 'Add all new entities' => 'Delete all deleted entities' => 'Update all dirty entities'.**

Once an entity is added to DB you can retrieve as a result its [@@IDENTITY/ SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) and then update its `Id` using any appropriate solution.

Comment: How can you add to the db a row that has foreign key constraints ? Your solution seems to make a temporary referencerence to a non existing ID . This workaround does not sound good .

Comment: Anyway your solution is not good for complex, nested auto_generated objects . How many persist calls you should do on the dirty/new objects ? This might seem impossible and not a good solution for complex transactions .

Comment: @Geo C. I do not support 'temporary reference to a non existing ID' at all. If row has foreign key constraints then these constraint should be added before (e.g. correct usage of NHibernates inverse solves it). So, **first you add all referenced entities, then you add row that has foreign keys to those entities**. If one knows order of calls to DB then it is possible to form rules for code.

Comment: @GeoC. "How many persist calls you should do on the dirty/new objects ?" I do one call per new, one call per deleted, one call per dirty entity. But you have many options. **First** - every `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` is separate call from your application to DB (in my case I used stored procedures for complex solution). **Second** - you can somehow combine generated SQL to reduce a number of calls to DB. **Third** - you can simply use any ORM and configure it.