# Different Key in Table relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, database-first, table-relationships

I have a database with this structure

```
TASKs              SubTasks
=============================
Id (pk)            Id (pk)
Name               Name
TaskCode           ParentTaskCode
```

Now I need to connect `SubTasks` Table to `Tasks` using `Tasks.TaskCode` as the key in the relation between them, and Entity Framework does not allow me to do that, any ideas :) ?

**Note:** I do not own this database, so any changes to the structure cannot be done.

Comment: What does entity framework say about you trying to add the relation? Does making taskcode unique change anything?

Comment: I am using Database-first approach. I am using the Designer to add foreign keys. After creating an `Association...`, I specify the `Referential Constraint`, which comes my problem ?

Comment: The relation in db is not created?

Comment: The problem is that the SubTasks table refers to a non-key item in Tasks. The database will not let you create a foreign key reference for this, and EF won't let you create that association where no foreign key relationship is defined in the database. Until the database is fixed, the best you can do is a join, and select into a custom class that is built the way you want it.

Comment: Is `ParentTaskCode == TaskCode`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like.

```
public class Certificates
{
    [Key]
    public int CertID { get; set; }

    public Users User { get; set; }
    public Quiz Quiz { get; set; }
}

public class Users
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Certificates> Certificates { get; set; }
}

public class Quiz
{
    public int QuizID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Certificates> Certificates { get; set; }
}

public class cpdContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entitiy<Users>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Certificates)
            .WithRequired(c => c.User)  // or WithOptional
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("UserID")); //<- DB FK column name

        modelBuilder.Entitiy<Quiz>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Certificates)
            .WithRequired(c => c.Quiz)  // or WithOptional
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("QuizID")); //<- DB FK column name
    }
}
```

Moreover, In independent association, the foreign key (Association) is defined in the conceptual model.

To define the association in a conceptual model, we must add association set, association and navigation properties.

1. It is represented as separate object in ObjectStateManager. It has its own EntityState!
2. When building association you always need entitites from both ends of association
3. This association is mapped in the same way as entity.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432109/ef-model-with-code-first-independent-association-or-foreign-key-association)

Answer (score 0):

There might be something I do not understand...

Why do you want to use Task.TaskCode as a foreign key of SubTasks ?

If ID is the PK of Tasks, then remove TaskCode an use Task.ID as you fk reference

SubTasks.TaskID ----> Task.ID.

Also, some other advices on naming conventions.

- do not pluralize table names
- use "<%table%>ID" as name for your pk : exemple TaskID for task.
- use fk column as name for a fk : exemple "TaskID" as fk in your subtask table

Comment: **Note:** I do not own this database, so any changes to the structure cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVC for this then you can simply make composite viewmodel for above.

Without changing in EF you can do what you want.

Make class as

```
public class CompositeTaskSubtask
{
    public <namespace>.<tasktablename> taskmodel { get; set; }
    public <namespace>.<subtasktablename> subtaskmodel { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The problem is I need to fetch some data from the Database using the relation between them.

Comment: How you want to relate them?

Comment: When I select Subtasks, I want to get their Parent Task too.

Comment: you can try one thing. I haven't try but conceptually it may work.

Comment: check this out http://divyek-soni.blogspot.in/ I have done some computations. due to lack of time I can do upto this only. all the best.

Answer (score -1):

You can try adding a linking table called SubTask with its own primary key.  That way taskCode will not need to be primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE Task
(
    taskId int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    name nvarchar(50),
    taskCode nvarchar(50),
    CONSTRAINT Task_PK PRIMARY KEY(taskId)
)
GO


CREATE TABLE SubTask
(
    subTaskId int NOT NULL,
    taskId int NOT NULL,  -- must have a parent
    CONSTRAINT SubTask_PK PRIMARY KEY(subTaskId)
)
GO


ALTER TABLE SubTask ADD CONSTRAINT SubTask_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (taskId) REFERENCES [Task] (taskId) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
GO


ALTER TABLE SubTask ADD CONSTRAINT SubTask_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (subTaskId) REFERENCES [Task] (taskId) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
GO
```

Comment: Nice idea, but unfortunately I do not own the database to make any changes!!

Comment: If you are using database-first, don't you have to do something on the database first?

Comment: No, because this was created by another developer, and I need read-only access to it.

Comment: Can't you at least create another database and migrate the all or at least some of the data to a new model?

Comment: It is part of another application. But what I need is a solution for this problem, because it can happen in the future or in other scenarios.