# Cascading insert with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Street { get; set; }

    public string Postcode { get; set; }
}

class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TestDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnectionString")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

Above are the model definitions and DbContext difinitions. I want to add a new address for the user, so i wrote my code as bellow:

```
var context = new TestDbContext();

var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(item => item.ID == 1);

user.Addresses.Add(new Address()
{
    City = "City",
    Street = "Street",
    Postcode = "Postcode",
});

context.SaveChanges();
```

**My doubt is why there are 3 SQL queries are executed in this code?**

1. It's generated in FirstOrDefault

   ```
   SELECT TOP (1) 
     [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
     [Extent1].[EmailAddress] AS [EmailAddress]
     FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
     WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[ID]
   ```
2. It's generated in user.Addresses.Add

   ```
   exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
       [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
       [Extent1].[City] AS [City], 
       [Extent1].[Street] AS [Street], 
       [Extent1].[Postcode] AS [Postcode], 
       [Extent1].[User_ID] AS [User_ID]
       FROM [dbo].[Addresses] AS [Extent1]
       WHERE ([Extent1].[User_ID] IS NOT NULL) 
         AND ([Extent1].[User_ID] = @EntityKeyValue1)',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=1
   ```
3. It's generated in SaveChanges

   ```
   exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[Addresses]([City], [Street], [Postcode], [User_ID])
   VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3)
   SELECT [ID]
   FROM [dbo].[Addresses]
   WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ID] = scope_identity()',N'@0 nvarchar(max) ,@1 nvarchar(max) ,@2 nvarchar(max) ,@3 int',@0=N'City',@1=N'Street',@2=N'Postcode',@3=1
   ```

   **How can I avoid the second SQL?**

Answer (score 2):

The `Addresses` nav property is lazy loading when you access the property (i.e. `user.Addresses`), which is why you're getting the second SQL command.

Try disabling lazy loading and see if that works (don't forget to initialize the `Addresses` property in a constructor for `User` e.g.:

```
public User()
{
    Addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can even prevent the first two queries!

You already know the user's ID value, so all you have to do is set the foreign key value in `Address`. Of course, `Address` should have this property:

```
public class Address
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }

    public int UserID { get; set; } // Set this property
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

The pair `User` and `UserID` is called a [foreign key association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations), which is the preferred way to deal with associations in EF (precisely because it can reduce the number of queries).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the class definition slightly:

```
public class Address
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Street { get; set; }

    public string Postcode { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set;}
}
```

so that now you can write:

```
var context = new TestDbContext();
var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(item => item.ID == 1);

context.Addresses.Add(new Address()
{
    City = "City",
    Street = "Street",
    Postcode = "Postcode",
    User = user
});

context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out the problem here is your `Addresses` property is a navigation property so when you access it EF is generating a `SELECT` statement to load the collection in. To avoid this from happening you have 2 options:

1. Eager load the addresses when you load the `User` so you take the hit when you first load the user e.g. `Users.Include(x => x.Addresses)`
2. Disable lazy loading on that particular property by making the `Addresses` property non-virtual

Answer (score 0):

I would add a `UserId` foreign key to the `Address` class, then I'd do this:

```
var context = new TestDbContext();

context.Addresses.Add(new Address()
{
    UserId = 1,
    City = "City",
    Street = "Street",
    Postcode = "Postcode",
});

context.SaveChanges();
```

No need to retrieve the user or the user's existing addresses

Foreign keys make Entity Framework is easier to use:

[Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx)

[Making Do with Absent Foreign Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708747.aspx)

And relationship fix-up will synchronise the navigation property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj713564.aspx