# Add existing column value as a new property on a model

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

So I believe I screwed up my initial models and missed an ID and Foreign Key property.
Entity Framework has figured this out anyway.... but now I want to fix up my models to correctly reflect this.

Originally my models were:-

```
public Season
{
    public int SeasonId {get; set;}
    public int Year {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<MatchFixture> MatchFixtures {get; set;}
}

public MatchFixture
{
    public int MatchFixtureId {get; set;}

    public int Round {get; set;}
    public string HomeTeam {get; set;}
    public string AwayTeam {get; set;}
}
```

Now I believe I should have MatchFixture have properties so it points to the Season that contains it, adding the following properties to MatchFixture.

```
public int SeasonId {get; set;}
public Season Season {get; set;}
```

But the issue is that my database already has a column in my MatchFixtures called Season_SeasonId. This is a nullable integer column, obviously coming from my containing collection in Season. If I originally had the properties above in MatchFixture, the column would just be called SeasonId, and be a *non-nullable* integer column.

What I want is for the values in that column to be transferred to my new column....

1. How do I do this using CodeFirst migrations? Should I rename the column, and change it to non-nullable, and we're done?
2. Should I even be adding these properties? I find it makes my code easier too navigate 'up the hierarchy' (i.e which Season does this MatchFixture exist in? matchFixture.Season, but I feel this is part of a bigger problem where my understand of Entity Framework is hampering me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one step, but you need to make sure first that there is no `NULL` value of `Season_SeasonId` in the database, if there is you need to do something about it, either remove it or set the foreign key value.

Just add these properties on `MatchFixture`.

```
public int SeasonId { get; set; }
public Season Season { get; set; }
```

Then enable, add and run the migration.

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
PM> Add-Migration AddMatchFixtureFK
PM> Update-Database
```

Then you have everything you need.

If you check the `AddMatchFixtureFK` migration, the `Up` method will have all steps necessary.

```
- Drop Foreign Key
- Drop Index
- Rename Column
- Alter Column (to non null-able)
- Create Index
- Add Foreign Key
```

Whether you need to add those properties or not, it has been explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations).
But one thing I found out that adding those navigation properties (id and reference) will make data manipulation and seed data become much easier. For example, you can add new `MatchFixture` to existing `Season` just by setting the `SeasonId`.