# How to update virtual property in EF6 Code First?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to update a virtual property using EF6 and MVC.
My code goes like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,Content,Image")] Recommendation recommendation, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (file != null)
                {
                   //we have an image - saving it to db
                    var image = Server.SaveFile(file, Request);
                    DB.Files.Add(image);
                    await DB.SaveChangesAsync();

                    //assign the new image to the recommendation
                    recommendation.Image = image;
                }

                recommendation.User = await GetLoggedInUserAsync();
                DB.Entry(recommendation).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await DB.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(recommendation);
        }
```

The image is saved in the `Files` table. Yet the `Image_Id` column in `Recommendations` table won't update to the new `Image_Id`. What am I missing here?

**Classes:**

```
     public class Item
     {
          [Key]
          public int Id { get; set; }
          public virtual ApplicationUser User{ get; set; }

         [Required]
         [DataType(DataType.Text)]
         [Display(Name = "Title")]
         public string Title { get; set; }

         [Required]
         [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
         [Display(Name = "Content")]
         public string Content { get; set; }
    }

    public class Recommendation : Item
    {
        [DisplayName("Image")]
        public virtual File Image { get; set; }
    }

    public class File
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }        
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Does `recommendation` has any relationship with other `Image` before updating ? Also show your classes, `Image` and `Recommendation`

Comment: Not always. But generally yes.

Comment: @YuliamChandra: I've added the classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, you are working with independent association (which has no foreign key ID), like.

```
public int ImageId { get; set; }
```

And you also works with disconnected object. So you need to maintain the relationship manually. You also have to delete the old relationship first before adding new relationship.

> If you are working with disconnected objects you **must manually** manage
>   the synchronization. - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee373856%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Try adding this code to manually manage the relationship.

```
var manager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)DB).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
// Removes previous relationship.
if (recommendation.Image != null)
{
    // If there is another image, but you don't remove it, the update will fail.
    manager.ChangeRelationshipState(recommendation, recommendation.Image,
        r => r.Image, EntityState.Deleted);
}

// Adds new relationship.
manager.ChangeRelationshipState(recommendation, image,
    r => r.Image, EntityState.Added);
```

Try to reconsider the class design to have the foreign key association.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations) for more information.

Comment: I've added the foreign key and it works. Thanks a lot!