# 3 way relationship: User, LOB and Role

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

Let's say we have User, Line Of Business (LOB) and Role. User have 1 LOB. But a user can also have number of roles within different LOBs.

The Code First model below creates 3 tables USERS, ROLES and LOBS. If left to his own devices it also creates UserRoles. Which is not what I want.

So far I've tried creating UserLOBRole {RoleId, UserId, LOBCode} object and marked all fields as composite primary, however EF barks about foreign key.

Is there any way I can describe such relationships in EF 4.1 code first?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId {get;set;}
    public string UserName {get;set;}
    public virtual LOB UserLOB {get;set;}

    // HOW DO I DEFINE RELATIONSHIP HERE? 
    public virtual ICollection<Role> UserRoles {get;set;}

}

public class Role
{
    public int RoleId {get;set;}
    public string RoleName {get;set;}
}

public class LOB
{
    public string LOBCode {get;set;}
    public string LobName {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible without exposing `UserLOBRole` as separate entity and interconnect `User`, `Role` and LOB through this new entity. Hiding junction table works only for many-to-many relation without any additional data but that is not this case.

```
public class UserLOBRole
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public string LOBCode { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LOBCode")]
    public virtual LOB LOB { get; set; }
}
```

Your code probably complains about FKs because [EF code first demands navigation property on at least one side of the realation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217441/ef4-code-first-how-to-add-a-relationship-without-adding-a-navigation-property/5217845#5217845) and your `LOB` and `Role` currently don't have it so `UserLOBRole` must have them.

And your `User` will now use:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId {get;set;}
    public string UserName {get;set;}
    public virtual LOB UserLOB {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<UserLOBRole> UserRoles {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is the only way. Will need to polish the API to answer quesions like "What Roles this user have", "does this user have a role in an lob" and so on.