# Is there any relationship between Foreign-key in the underline tables and the navigation properties in the model?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I'm kind of confuse with the navigation properties in the EF Code First.

The following 2 classes come from [ScottGu tutorial on EF Code First](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx).

```
public class Dinner
{
  public int DinnerID { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
  public string Address { get; set; }
  public string HostedBy { get; set; }   

  public virtual ICollection<RSVP> RSVPs { get; set; }   
}

public class RSVP
{
  public int RsvpID { get; set; }
  public int DinnerID { get; set; }
  public string AttendeeMail { get; set; }

  public virtual Dinner Dinner { get; set; }
}
```

They are 2 tables In the ScottGu's NerdDinner tutorial: **Dinners** and **RSVP**. The column DinnerID is the **primary-key** for Dinner and a **foreign-key** for RSVP.

Those are my questions:

1. I understand why there's a **ICollection RSVPs** property in the Diner class, but why a **Dinner Dinner** property in the RSVP class?
2. What's going to happen if I do not add the **DINER navigation property** in the RSVP class?

I can sum up all my questions by saying: "Isn't there any relationship between Foreign-key in the underline tables and the navigation properties in the model?"

Navigation properties are there to reflect the relationship between tables in the underline database or not?

I'm sorry to be so lengthy, I'm really confused.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations/5282275#5282275

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **ICollection RSVPs** property in the **Diner** class and     **Dinner** property in the **RSVP** class are the navigation properties
   which indicating that there is a one to many relationship between
   **Diner** and **RSVP**.Yes ,navigation properties are there to reflect the reationship.

   2.You can do like that. you should have a navigation property for at least one side to map the relationsip. [EF4 Code First: how to add a relationship without adding a navigation property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217441/ef4-code-first-how-to-add-a-relationship-without-adding-a-navigation-property)

Comment: At least I know that there's a relationship. Thanks